# java script, google extensions, understanding a method

Tags: javascript, function, syntax

The method that I going to talk about returns the current url browser address
in order to understand how does it works I would like to know why the function argument declares in this way as I know it`s have to be written like that 
function NAMEOFTHEFUNCTION(ARGUMENTS){}
I searched for "function inside function" but without finding someting that relevant
can someone explain me that syntax ?

```
chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
document.getElementById('currentLink').innerHTML = tab.url;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a callback function, `functionName(inputArgument, callbackFunction(){});`

`callbackFunction(){}` can be defined as it is in your code snippet as an anonymous function, or you can do it as such

```
chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, doStuff);

function doStuff(tab) {
    document.getElementById('currentLink').innerHTML = tab.url;
}
```

Comment: I think that I undertand what you explain me so I want to ask more few questions: 1) for me callback function is not diffrent from another regular function am i right? 2) the argument that named "tab" does not contains nothing so how it`s wrok? 3) can I set the value into variable? I don`t know if this function returns string mybe it is just a void function that "document.write" the url on the screen

Comment: 1) yes. a callback is just a function. 
2) I do not know for sure, but I believe that tabs contains the information about the current tabs that are open/ or about the one that is currently active. 
3) yes i believe you can set the value into a variable, though using tabs would be perfectly acceptable too.